# PowerAutomate Adaptive card needs to function as poll, how to accomplish this?

Tags: json, microsoft-teams, power-automate, polling, adaptive-cards

I'd like some help for this powerAutomate adaptive card I've made.  I got the backbone for the card from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/poll-generator-sample). However, when I post it in a teams channel, I can only select an option and click submit.

When I submit the "poll" it doesn't do anything. I'd like for the card to function like a poll, saving all votes and showing the results underneath (possibly with a view result button or through other means)

However, I'm not familiar with power automate :( please help :)

```
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "XXX's two-weekly dinner!   ",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "size": "ExtraLarge",
            "spacing": "None",
            "id": "acHeader"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "size": "Large",
            "text": "Will you join dinner / drinks after the coming retro on Thursday? ",
            "id": "acInstructions",
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "placeholder": "Select from these choices",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Yes",
                    "value": "yes"
                },
                {
                    "title": "No",
                    "value": "no"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Maybe, who knows?",
                    "value": "maybe"
                }
            ],
            "id": "acPollChoices",
            "style": "expanded"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit",
            "id": "btnSubmit"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: We also followed the same [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/poll-generator-sample) and noticed that though the adaptive card gets posted, the responses are not visible. This seems like implementing view result feature like poll is not feasible for card sent using Power Automate.